# after a geolocation google maps addlistener click stop working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, geolocation

I have a form to put the address where the user can click over the google map and the inputs country, estate, county, address are filled automatically, but also if the user wants to fill the inputs with text, automatically geolocalize on the map. both of functions works properly but after the user fill the inputs text and geolocalitation is done if I click over the map the addlistener does not work any more.

the entire code is to long, so I just put in here the most important parts

```
function geolocalizarTM(){
console.log("entre en geolocalizarTM");
var gmap, divmap;
divmap = $('#map');
d1  = document.getElementById('direccion1').value; 
d2 = document.getElementById('direccion2').value; 
num = document.getElementById('numero').value; 
codp = document.getElementById('codigo_postal').value; 
prov = document.getElementById('provincia_id').value;
pob = document.getElementById('poblacion_id').value;
country = document.getElementById('pais_id').value;
if((d1!="")&& (codp!="")&&(prov!="")&&(pob!="")&&(country!="")){
    direccionText = d1 + "," + num + "," + codp + "," + prov + "," + pob + "," + country;                    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + direccionText + "&key=AIzaSyCy96_rJ419QasmI4RaJs3uHO-PUh-bNuc",
        dataType: "json",
        success: processJSON
    });
function processJSON(json) {
    lat = json.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    lon = json.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

    latLon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    objConfig = new Object();

    objConfig.zoom = 18;
    objConfig.center = latLon;
    gmap = new google.maps.Map(divmap[0], objConfig);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLon,
        map: gmap,
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(gmap);
    marker.setMap(gmap);
    }
}
};


var ul = document.getElementById('panelContenedor');
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService;
var lat, lon, latLon, objConfig, ubicacionProd;
ubicacionProd = "";

var gmap, divmap;
divmap = $('#map');
showMap();
function showMap() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(fn_ok, fn_error);
}
function fn_error() {
    console.log('geolocalizacion, ha ocurrido un error...');
}
function fn_ok(resp) {
    console.log("inicializo el mapa");
    lat = resp.coords.latitude;
    lon = resp.coords.longitude;
    latitud = document.getElementById("latitud").value;
    longitud = document.getElementById("longitud").value;
    if (latitud != "" && longitud != "") {
        lat = latitud;
        lon = longitud;
    }
   latLon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
   objConfig = new Object();
   objConfig.zoom = 18;
   objConfig.center = latLon;
   gmap = new google.maps.Map(divmap[0], objConfig);

directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLon,
});
directionsDisplay.setMap(gmap);

marker.setMap(gmap);

google.maps.event.addListener(gmap, 'click', function (e) {
    fx(e.latLng);
});

function fx(latLng) {
    console.log("pinche el mapa");
    marker.setMap(null);
    $('#localizacion').val(latLng);
    var request = {
        origin: latLng,
        destination: latLng,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        console.log(response);

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var point = response.routes[0].legs[0];
        marker.setOptions({map: gmap, position: point.start_location});
        gmap.setCenter(point.start_location);
        var direction = response.routes[0].legs[0].start_address.split(",");

    }
        /****aqui debo llenar los campos de la direccion****/
        console.log("Direccion: [0]" + direction[0] + "** [1]" + direction[1] + "** [2]" + direction[2] + "** [3]" + direction[3] + "** [4]" + direction[4] + '\n');
        var num_posiciones = direction.length; // determinamos el numero de campos que trae el arreglo
        /* blanqueo las cajitas*/
        $('#direccion1').val("");
        $('#direccion2').val("");
        $('#pais_id').val("");
        $('#provincia_id').val("");
        $('#numero').val("");
        $('#codigo_postal').val("");
        $('#poblacion_id').val("");
        /*

        ** here I fill the inputs ***

        */
    });
}
}
```

I hope you can help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I already resolve the problem. I was that I did not call the function fn_ok() after proscessJson function. that's why google.maps.event.addListener(gmap, 'click', function (e)  did not work.

so, I hope this post could be usefull to someone.